# I need to install NPOI package into a SSIS task script

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, xlsx, npoi

I would like to use NPOI package to convert a .csv file into an .xlsx.
I am trying with NPOI package bcos I can not use ACE.OLEDB neither any library which need office installed on the machine.

Is the first time I tried to do this , so I followed these instructions:

https://blog.matrixpost.net/load-an-custom-assembly-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-script-task-that-is-not-or-cannot-be-stored-in-the-gac/

but does not work , when I run the corflags command appears it does not have access to read the folder.

[image: SSIS error]]

[image: corflags error]

Any advice would be great, thanks in advance!

--Attached a part of the script code.---------

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI;
#endregion

namespace ST_14f74128896f4ec2939bbe171ead9c74
{
 
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        

        public void Main()
        {
            string pathCsv = Dts.Variables["User::Pathcsv"].Value.ToString();
            char splitter = ',';
            var newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(pathCsv, ".xlsx");

            //All read all the lines present in the csv file
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathCsv, Encoding.UTF8);

            //Create the excek file 
            IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(Path.GetFileName(newFileName));
            var rowIndex = 0;[....]
```

I tried to istalled the NPOI package using gac and customizing the package, but does not work.
Furthermore, I installed the Npoi package through the Nuget package, but the script is not working.

I am not sure what else I can do or what I have done wrong.

Comment: Why do this at all? CSV isn't an Excel file, it's just a text file with commas. The SSIS Flat File data source can handle it easily. SSIS also has an Excel target. In any case you *can't* use NuGet in SSIS scripts at all. That task was created long before there was NuGet. Any DLLs needed have to be deployed along with the solution

Comment: What you try to do is no different than using SSIS as a task scheduler to run an external program. It would be a lot easier to create a Console program that does what you want and use a Process task to execute it

Comment: BTW ACE does *not* need Office installed. In fact, Office causes extra trouble. All you need to do is install the correct driver

Comment: Hi everyone for the adivices. I know there are easier ways to do it, but I do not have to use ACE OLEDB, what resource should I install to use a process task? can u recommend one, please?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, how can I install correctly the .dll in the solution? As I said I have tried using gac but has not worked. Thanks in advance for any suggestions